# Meteor,db is not defined error mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am using meteor.JS to develop simple app and i have some problem here.

In my app i defined collection like below and i published it from server side and subscribed it in client side

```
Product_Mobiles=new Meteor.Collection('product_mobiles');
```

while running the app in one terminal,from the other terminal  i imported JSON file data to collection like

```
mongoimport --db meteor --host localhost:3002 --collection Product_Mobiles <products.json --jsonArray
```

that imports the objects well and my problem is,

when i try to call

```
db.Product_Mobile.find({});
```

this showing error db is not defined. that command is working well in `meteor mongo` shell and returning results.

But when i try this in JS file and while running the app it is showing `db not defined` and i tried to remove the db and run like

`Product_Mobile.find({});`(which i did to all my remaining collections and those are working well).

This is also showing error like **Product_Mobile is not defined** Am i doing anything wrong?
Help me with this.

Comment: What Akshat said. See also the [documentation for Collections](http://docs.meteor.com/#collections) in Meteor. No need for `db.`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the collection name you defined with `Product_Mobiles=new Meteor.Collection('product_mobiles');`

So you should use `product_mobiles` when you import something.

Additionally in meteor the commands aren't exactly the same as the mongo shell. You would use `Product_Mobiles.find()` instead, since you defined it earlier on. The `db` object is only something thats available in the mongo shell.